# Как работает метод get() в aiohttp.ClientSession()?

Tags: python, request, asyncio, aiohttp

Изучаю библиотеку aiohttp. Столкнулся с некоторым недопониманием в работе метода get() в aiohttp.ClientSession()

Значит есть следующий код:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
            status_code = resp.status
            print(status_code)
            body = await resp.text()
            print(body)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

В итоге, получаем следующие значения переменных:

**resp** = объект класса ClientResponse.

**status_code** = число 200. То есть http статус код ответа от сервера.

**body** = строковое значение с html телом страницы.

Но, я не могу понять, зачем для того чтоб получить html тело страницы писать следующее выражение **await resp.text()** ? Что мы тут ждем? Разве еще раз обращаемся к серверу за телом страницы? Если да, тогда смысл это делать если мы ранее уже обращались к серверу с этим же запросом, при этом получили ответ 200?

Почему нельзя просто взять объект **resp** и сразу же получить у него тело страницы? По аналогии, как я получаю код ответа, то есть **resp.status** (там никакого *await* нет).

============================================

Я пробовал возвращать **resp.text()** без *await* но в итоге получаю объект класса *Coroutine* вместо строки с телом страницы.

============================================

Объясните, пожалуйста, такое странное поведение данной конструкции. И, если я прав на счет повторного запроса, как его избежать? То есть, как мне взять из объекта **resp** сразу код ответа сервера и тело ответа с html кодом страницы?

Comment: Метод `get` делает запрос, а `await resp.text()` ждёт ответ. Вы же не считаете, что тело страницы передаётся мгновенно?

Comment: но тогда я не понимаю, откуда у объекта **resp** появилось значение кода ответа сервера 200 ? Ведь для этого нужно получить ответ от сервера. Если получили заголовки ответа в которых есть код ответа 200, значит и тело ответа должно быть рядом. Смысл тогда он возвращает код ответа 200 но не дает тело страницы?

Comment: Заголовки http-ответа обычно умещаются в один tcp-пакет, а тело имеет неограниченный размер и может занимать десятки мегабайт или даже больше.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю. То есть, все таки тут есть два запроса к серверу? Первый на получения чисто заголовков ответа сервера из которых получаем код ответа 200. И второй запрос уже через await resp.text() ? Мне главное понять, есть ли тут два запроса к серверу?

Comment: Нет, запрос один. Если вас интересует, как это работает под капотом, то стоит познакомиться с мультиплексированием неблокирующихся сокетов.

Comment: Нет, меня не интересует как оно там под капотом реализовано. Я просто работаю через прокси и в конце мне нужно распарсить тело ответа сервера. Ведь, было бы намного удобнее просто сохранить полученные объекты **resp** в список. И после того как event_loop отработал, пройтись по этим объектам в цикле. Извлечь с каждого объекта код ответа и тело ответа и выпарсить нужные данные. Но тут так не выходит. Смысл мне отдавать код ответа 200 если я не получил само тело ответа с кодом страницы?

Comment: Асинхронность так не работает. Можете добавить в список сопрограммы,  поставить колбэк на завершение их всех и выполнить в нём нужные вам действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не повторный запрос, просто код прерывается получив заголовки. На основе заголовков можешь решить нужно ли тебе тело ответа.

или/и

Размер страницы может быть пару килобайт, а может быть больше. Время затраченное на скачивания содержимого страницы можно провести с пользой выполнив ещё несколько асинхронных заданий. К примеру, если откроете инспектор в браузере, то можно увидеть что браузер запрашивает следующую картинку не приняв текущую до конца.

или/и

Если же размер ответа несколько сотен мегабайт или вообще видео/аудио поток - то тело ответа можно передать читалке и вычитывать небольшими кусочками не помещая в память, а воспроизводя на экран или записывая на диск.